# Azure logic app use a variable inside inline_code action

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that looks something like this:
[image]

In the js code action, I just wanted to check if the name of the file (that had triggered the workflow) match some pattern. So my Inline code action has something like:

```java
    var input = workflowContext.trigger.outputs.headers.x-ms-file-name;
    if(input.match(/^([0-9]){3}_Hello/))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
```

However, it seems that the action can't get the file name because the `x-ms-file-name` is splitted by a '-'.
So, I tried to solve this problem by creating a variable called `fileName` in an the action before it
[image]

and then use it in the inline code action. But I don't know how to call the variable inside inline code action.
What should I write here:

```java
    var input = ????;
    if(input.match(/^([0-9]){3}_Hello/))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
```

Any suggestion to how to solve this problem?

Note (I am not sure if it is relevant but in case it helps): I am using the standard logic app so I amp supposed to not have/use Integration account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I can just simply write the following in the inline action:

```js
    var input = workflowContext.trigger.outputs.headers['x-ms-file-name'];
    if(input.match(/^([0-9]){3}_Hello/))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
```